# How to read excel file from user and generating Google Sheet file

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to allow user upload excel (xlsx) file and then generate a Google Sheets file using Google Scripts (the generated file uses the input file values, process them with certain formulas and provides another excel file as output based on all processing)

I am currently doing the task in a simple desktop application (using MS Excel etc.), but problem is I have admin rights and I want other people to do the same on their PCs but they dont have admin rights, so please help me with this, whats the best way I can implement it via Google Sheets. I need following to do:

- Get an XLSX file from user
- Read two columns using google sheet script.
- Process the read values and create a new google sheet file with 6/7 columns

Plz help as I am not looking for a ready made code but a head start, as I have never worked with google scripts before.

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to study the basics of [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) in general, and of the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) and [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) in specific.
- The steps to write your code would be

  - retrieving the excel file on your Google Drive
  - retrieving its [blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob)
  - [creating a new file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) of the mimeType `GOOGLE_SHEETS` with the contents of your blob
  - Once you create a Google Spreadsheet - process it with the SpreadsheetApp methods to delete spare contents/ create a copy with only the desired contents.

[Here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet) you can find useful samples.

> Note: It might make sense to retrieve the columns of interest before
>   converting them to Google Sheets, but this is not something you can do
>   with Apps Script or a Google API since they do not have methods to
>   edit Excel files.