# Save a excel file as gsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-sheets-api, xlsx

I want to automate a process and i have working with python, selenium and vba. 
My process starts with a downloaded file from SQL server with python and selenium, later with vba, I transform the file and i apply a lot of formulas. When i finish, i save the file in xlsx format on a google drive folder with google File Stream. When the file is save on the folder, with google script i send a mail with the file's url. The final objetive of all this, it's that the users will put observations on de xlsx in the google drive folder, but on this format i don't have a way to change the file on collaborative way.
There's a method to save an excel file on gsheet format with MS excel or automate the transformation of the xlsx to gsheet and later send the email with the new file's url?
Greetings!

Comment: What code have you written so far to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need the codes @ross? maybe, i could privately send you all interactions and all codes in vba, python and google scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can automatically convert an MS Excel file to a Google spreadsheet with the Google Drive API

See a sample under [Import to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types_).

You just need to change the mimeType from `'text/csv'` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` or similar, depending on the [extension](https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.html) of your Excel file.

PS: Since you tagged your question with `google-apps-script`: In Google Apps Script you can do the conversion as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59578547/11599789).

Comment: thank you so much @ziganotschka. With your answer i found this link with some goods examples: https://www.labnol.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code with the solution:

```
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet() {


var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('put the id's folder here')
var excelFile = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL).next();
var fileId = excelFile.getId();
var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;
var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
var resource = {
  title: excelFile.getName(),
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{id: folderId}],
};

Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
}
```

Later, you need remove the excel files with this script:

```
   function remove(){
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('put you folder's id here');
   var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);;
   while (files.hasNext()){
   var file = files.next();
   folder.removeFile(file);
   }
```

The third step is put the notification:

```
     function checkForChangedFiles() {

     // folder
     var folderID = '"' + "folder's id" + '"';

     // email configuration
     var emailFromName ="emailname";
     var emailSubject = "emailsubject";
     var emailBody = "<b><br>bodyemail:<br></b>" +
     "line1<br>" +
     "line2<br>"+
     "line3<br>"+
     "line4<br>";
      var emailFooter = "footer";

      var folderSearch = folderID + " " + "in parents";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var email = sheet.getRange("put the cell with the email's values").getValue();
      var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
      var today     = new Date();
      var time = new Date(today.getTime() - 1 * 30 * 1000);  // 30 seconds
      var startTime = time.toISOString();
      var search = '(trashed = true or trashed = false) and '+ folderSearch +' and (modifiedDate > "' + startTime + '")';   

      var files  = DriveApp.searchFiles(search);
      var row = "", count=0;

      while( files.hasNext() ) {

      var file = files.next();
      var fileName = file.getName();
      var fileURL  = file.getUrl();
      var lastUpdated =  Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated(), timezone, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
      var dateCreated =  Utilities.formatDate(file.getDateCreated(), timezone, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")

      row += "<li>" + lastUpdated + " <a href='" + fileURL + "'>" + fileName + "</a></li>";

      sheet.appendRow([dateCreated, lastUpdated, fileName, fileURL]);

      count++;
      }


      if (row !== "") {

      row = "<p>" + count + "  New File:</p><ol>" + row + "</ol>";
      row +=  emailBody+"<br>" + "<br><small> "+emailFooter+" </a>.</small>";     
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, emailSubject, "", {name: emailFromName, htmlBody: row});
      }
```

And finally we put all together:

```
      function doall(){
      convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet();
      Utilities.sleep(10000);
      remove();
      Utilities.sleep(10000);
      checkForChangedFiles();

      }
```